# JSF: selectOneListBox with checkboxes

Tags: jsf, checkbox, selectonelistbox

Is it possible to create a selectOneListBox with checkboxes? And if so, how to do this or what would be the best approach? I do not want to do this using Primefaces, I only have license to Richfaces atm.

```
<h:selectOneListBox>
      ............
</h:selectOneListBox>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: License to RichFaces? For PF you don't need a license..

Comment: Is this just a cosmetic thing or do you really need the checkbox functionality?

Comment: why not use `h:selectManyListBox` where you would get multi select option by default?